# What is happening to my peace lilly?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

It is hunched over and new leaves are growing from its behind.
[image]

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 4):

This plant is growing towards the light. It needs a quarter turn once a week.

You can also add more soil to give it more support.

Another good thing to do would be to move it right up against the window as there is more light the closer it is.

Finally, I can't see any drainage for the pot.  Even a spath which likes to be kept moist can rot if the roots are wet constantly.  Ensure there is a way for water to drain out of the pot after a good watering.

Comment: Good point about root rot, but I do see a clear plastic saucer under the pot (implying there may be drainage).